# Synchronize nexus build number with hudson/jenkins build number 

Tags: maven, hudson, nexus, jenkins

I would like to tell nexus to give a deployed snapshot the same build number as jenkins assigned to the build.

To clarify:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
  <groupId>com.bmw.psdz</groupId>
  <artifactId>psdz-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <versioning>
    <snapshot>
      <timestamp>20110304.122623</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>4</buildNumber> <!-- this should be same build number as jenkins assigned to the build -->
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20110304122623</lastUpdated>
    <snapshotVersions>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>4.3.3-20110304.122623-4</value>
        <updated>20110304122623</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>pom</extension>
        <value>4.3.3-20110304.122623-4</value>
        <updated>20110304122623</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
    </snapshotVersions>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

In Hudson/Jenkins you can use `${BUILD_NUMBER}` as a parameter in your builds.  Pass this in to your maven build like `mvn clean package -Dbuild.number=${BUILD_NUMBER}`, or use it in post-build steps as you like.

This may help you towards an answer, but I don't know enough Nexus to provide a complete solution.

Answer (score -1):

If it was me, I'd be looking to use a released version of the artefact in maven\nexus if I cared about the version information.  I wouldn't normally care (a\or want to) differentiate between different SNAPSHOT versions.

Would it work for you to use the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) to create a version as part of the build?  This could include the Hudson build number and\or the VCS revision number as part of your versioning scheme.

Comment: We use the snapshots to verify bugfixes before building a final release. I could create x.y.z-RC1 etc. releases for this purpose but it would be more complicated than just using the snapshots. A maven release takes more time than a snapshot build, because due to the nature of maven-release-plugin everything is build twice.

Comment: Hi Daniel.  Yes, the maven-release-plugin can be a bit cumbersome.  Have a look at this blog which offers an alternative approach - http://www.dzone.com/links/r/maven_releases_on_steroids_adios_release_plugin.html.  It allows you to version cheaply, but does have some constraints as well...

Comment: Alternatively, couldn't you just do a "mvn deploy" and include the build number in the version by passing it in as a parameter (as a SNAPSHOT if you prefer).